# Why do function argument names need to match list names with pmap?

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to understand why this code works:

```
tmp <- list(this = list(1:5), 
            that = list(10*c(1:5)), 
            other = list(100*c(1:5))) 

tmp %>% pmap(function(this, that, other) paste(this, that, other))
```

... but the following code produces an "unused arguments" error:

```
tmp %>% pmap(function(a, b, c) paste(a, b, c))
```

I came across [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/280) GitHub post, but I'm still not clear on how it might apply.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a named list as shown in the example, you need to refer them with their respective names in an anonymous function. Hence, this works for a named list

```
library(purrr)
tmp %>% pmap(function(this, that, other) paste(this, that, other))
```

and this does not.

```
tmp %>% pmap(function(a, b, c) paste(a, b, c))
```

If you remove the names of the list then you can use any variable in the argument.

```
unname(tmp) %>% pmap(function(a, b, c) paste(a, b, c))

#[[1]]
#[1] "1 10 100" "2 20 200" "3 30 300" "4 40 400" "5 50 500"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling to see how this would be different from a function you might pass in an `lapply` setting -- 'anonymous function' might be the key word I need to look up.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missunderstanding your question, the second doesn't work because `a`, `b` and `c` are not list elements that are attached in the pmap's calling environment.

If you named the list elements `a`, `b` and `c`, it would work.

```
tmp2 <- list(a = list(1:5), 
            b = list(10*c(1:5)), 
            c = list(100*c(1:5))) 

tmp2 %>% pmap(function(a, b, c) paste(a, b, c))
#[[1]]
#[1] "1 10 100" "2 20 200" "3 30 300" "4 40 400" "5 50 500"
```

Could you have objects named `a`, `b` or `c` in your global environment? I get a different error message.

```
tmp %>% pmap(function(a, b, c) paste(a, b, c))
#Error in .f(this = .l[[1L]][[1L]], that = .l[[2L]][[1L]], other = .l[[3L]][[1L]],  : 
#  unused arguments (this = .l[[1]][[1]], that = .l[[2]][[1]], other = .l[[3]][[1]])

packageVersion("purrr")
#[1] ‘0.3.3’
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this without any anonymous function

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
tmp %>%
     pmap(paste)
#[[1]]
#[1] "1 10 100" "2 20 200" "3 30 300" "4 40 400" "5 50 500"
```

---

Also, with `tidyverse`, the anonymous syntax can be

```
tmp %>%
   pmap(~ paste(..1, ..2, ..3))
#[[1]]
#[1] "1 10 100" "2 20 200" "3 30 300" "4 40 400" "5 50 500"
```